# Always get same data from clf model. How do I properly clone using sklearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, clone, sklearn-pandas

Every time I pass in the same model to my fit_model function, I get the same output because sklearn copies the results when I access clf again. How do I properly clone?

I've reviewed documentation, examples of using sklearn.base.clone and tried wrapping several different model-based objects in clone but am unable to decouple the predetermined model results and have a fresh run when accessing my fit_model function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import warnings
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.base import clone

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/mmcgown/Downloads/Yeast.csv",names = ['sample','mcg', 'gvh', 'alm', 'mit', 'erl', 'pox', 'vac', 'nuc','site'])
df=df.drop(columns=['sample'])
target = 'site'
#Used to take an initial look at the categories of fields
print(df.head())

#Histogram to show overall distribution of each field, count vs values. Tight layout prevents overlap of axis labels.
df.hist()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#Scatter matrix to show the relation of each field to each other, erl/pox have little interaction since the above distribution is skewed
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
scatter_matrix(df)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#Below shows the unique values in each column. I have commented it out but I use it to see the unique data in each column.
[df[x].unique().shape[0] for x in df.columns]
#It is [81, 79, 52, 77, 2, 3, 47, 60, 10] which means erl/pox amino acids (columns 5,6) are going to be hard to identify by ML
#The last value is site which we have 10 different site types

#***************************************************INPUTS***********************************************************************

#Below are Naive Bayes model types
#These are the three models we'll be testing. To best attempt F_score maxima, models will have no prior fit from previous attempts.
#GaussianNB is false in this way by default.
model_type = [BernoulliNB(fit_prior=False),GaussianNB(),MultinomialNB(fit_prior=False)]

#Neural nets can also be used but will take longer to converge
#model_type = [MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2)),MLPClassifier(solver='adam', alpha=1e-5,max_iter=10000,hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2)),MLPClassifier(solver='sgd', alpha=1e-5,max_iter=10000,hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2))]

#The model(s) will probably not be able to predict all amino acid sites. What is the max # of sites left unpredicted?
#Constraining to a number lower than 8 will result in more 0 fit scores and lower average fit scores
no_site_tolerance = 3
#Each model/train size/seeds converges on a different solution. How many subdivisions of starting points would you like to try?
seeds = 10
#The model(s) perform differently with different amounts of training. How many equally spaced percentages would you like to send?
train_steps = 10

#*******************************************************************************************************************************

#Makes ndarray of equally spaced train fractions to send to the model.
train_frac = np.linspace(0.1,0.9,train_steps)
#Makes ndarray of equally spaced starting points for the model to find convergence over the sample space.
states = np.linspace(0,df.shape[0],seeds, dtype=int)

#Identify the target field we are aiming to predict. In this case it is the amino acid site.
Y = df[target]
#Prepare to make the fields we aim to train & guess off of with our model as X. Remove the target site column.
df2 = df.drop(columns=[target])
#df2.columns is Index(['mcg', 'gvh', 'alm', 'mit', 'erl', 'pox', 'vac', 'nuc'], dtype='object').
#X is now every except the target site.
X = df[df2.columns[:]]

#This class assesses the fitness metrics of the trained model
def fit_model(X,Y,states,model,train_size,no_site_tolerance):
    #Iterate over each starting point seed, a different starting state
    for state in states:
        #Take the model type passed in
        clf = model
        #train_test_split randomly splits the data into a train_size fraction of how much data the model is trained with
        X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=train_size, random_state=state)
        #the model is fitted based on the training data
        clf = clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        #Ignoring warnings from model because it may not be able to have sufficient data to predict every site
        #The storage and constraining of ill_defined_sites is how we control/interpret what this warn concerns
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            #Precision & Recall are each different statistical measures of fitness
            #Precision is true positives/(true positives + false positives)
            precision = metrics.precision_score(Y_test, clf.predict(X_test), average='weighted')
            #Recall is true positives/(true positives + false negatives)
            recall    = metrics.recall_score(Y_test, clf.predict(X_test), average='weighted')
            #F score is the weighted mean of precision and recall
            f_score = 2/(1/precision+1/recall)
        #ill defined sites finds the set of sites that couldn't be predicted by the model this run
        ill_defined_sites = set(Y_test) - set(clf.predict(X_test))
        #that then allows us to constrain, from input, if the model is unfit no matter the f_score
        if len(ill_defined_sites) <= no_site_tolerance:
            #if there were enough predictable sites, pass in the f_score
            F = f_score
        else:
            #if not, give an F score of 0
            F = 0
        #Make two dictionaries with each starting model state as the keys
        #One dictionary is the resultant F score and the other is the ill defined sites e.g. MIT, NUC
        results_params[state],results_sites[state] = F, ill_defined_sites
    #Send these two dictionaries as the results
    return results_params, results_sites

#Set parameter names to be part of dictionary
params = ['F','state','train_size']
#Create empty dictionary of these parameter names
param_dict = {param: None for param in params}
#Create empty dictionary to be filled with each model to each parameter dictionary
model_dict = {model_name: param_dict for model_name in model_type}
#Iterate over input model types
for model in model_type:
    #Make empty dictionaries for interim use
    df3_params, df3_sites, results_params,results_sites = {},{},{},{}
    #Iterate over what fraction of data is fed to model
    for train_size in train_frac:
        #Obtain results as dictionaries of seed sample states to each resultant F_score/ill_defined_sites from the model
        results_params, results_sites = fit_model(X,Y,states,model,train_size,no_site_tolerance)
        #Put each result in a dictionary for the train size used
        df3_params.update({train_size:pd.Series(results_params)})
        df3_sites.update({train_size:pd.Series(results_sites)})

    #Make empty dictionary to be filled with the best parameters for each model
    best = {}
    #Iterate over the train sizes to store the best F_score and its best parameters
    for key in df3_params.keys():
        #If this F_score is the first one or the maximum so far, store the settings
        if not best or best['F'] < df3_params[key].max():
            #Store this in the best dictionary
            best = {'train_size':key,'state':df3_params[key].idxmax(),'F':df3_params[key].max()}
    #If the highest F_score for that model was not 0
    if best['F']:
        #Store the best settings and F_score for each model
        model_dict.update({model:best})
    else:
        #Drop that model from the dictionary if it has no F_score
        model_dict.pop(model)

#Make empty dictionary to store the best model and its settings in
results_params, results_sites, best_model = {}, {}, {}

for model in model_dict.keys():
    if not best_model or best_model['F'] < model_dict[model]['F']:
        model_train_size = model_dict[model]['train_size']
        model_state = model_dict[model]['state']
        model_F = model_dict[model]['F']
        best_sites = df3_sites[model_train_size][model_state]
        best_model = {'model': model,'state':model_state,'train_size':model_train_size,'F':model_F,'sites':best_sites}

results_params,results_sites = fit_model(X,Y,states,best_model['model'],best_model['train_size'],no_site_tolerance)

#Find out how much the avg_F of a model run with optimal parameters differs from the best F obtained from all models/train sizes/seeds
#Note that lower inputs of no_site_tolerance get more 0 F_scores, increasing the delta between avg_F and best_model F.
total = 0
for key in results_params.keys():
    total += results_params[key]
avg_F = total/len(results_params.keys())

import re
title = re.search('[^(]*',str(best_model['model']))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(results_params.keys(), results_params.values(), color='orange',marker='*')
for key,value in zip(results_params.keys(),results_params.values()):
    plt.annotate(xy=(key,value),s=len(results_sites[key]),xytext=(key*1.00,value*1.00),ha='left',va='bottom',color='blue')
plt.axhline(y=avg_F,linewidth=2, color='g')
plt.axhline(y=best_model['F'],linewidth=2, color='black')
plt.title(title.group(0)+' Best Parameter Fit w/ Missing Sites')
plt.xlabel('Seed Samples')
plt.ylabel('F_Score');
```

[image]
https://github.com/markamcgown/Projects/blob/master/Yeast%20Project.ipynb
https://github.com/markamcgown/Projects/blob/master/Yeast.csv

Comment: I may also have a superfluous clf = clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example. See [MWE help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: One `clf.fit` is most likely superfluous, and so is splitting the data set twice. if I understand your code correctly, anything computed in `train_model` is discarded later on.

Comment: I think you are right about train_model. Are you saying train_test_split already does everything train_model does? Fit is still needed otherwise there's a specific error saying the model I am trying needs to be fit first. I'll include a github link to the full code (train_model removed) and csv to import if you can show me how clone needs to be.

Comment: Your code here is different from the code on github. Please read the help page above again, and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here on stackoverflow. Also, please show us the output of the unexpected results. Otherwise, it is hard for us to help you.

Comment: I have updated to include my full code and the final image. I was not expecting the black horizontal line of the best F of all models to always be touching the data. That is because I was thinking the final fit_model with the best parameters would have independent results, that is the orange line. As it is, I believe either every clf model converges the same with the same inputs or I am not clearing out clf.

Comment: This is complicated code and certainly not minimal, but I'll try to help. So you train various models, store the best, and retrain with the best configuration, right? When you fit, you split the data using fixed random states. So my guess is, that all your classifiers and splits are deterministic. Thus are the results.

Comment: Your description is accurate and I appreciate the input. My guess is similar but I'm not 100% certain that's the case, most importantly given the existence of sklearn.base.clone. I will make it more minimal in the future, I realize your point.